# Field label disappeared when validating input

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have a very simple form and a strange behaviour:

```
<form name='signup_form' novalidate ng-submit=signupForm()>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large12 columns">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email"
        name="email"
        ng-model="signup.email"
        required />
      <div class="error" ng-show="signup_form.email.$dirty && 
                                  signup_form.email.$invalid">
        <small class="error" ng-show="signup_form.email.$error.required">
          Email address is required
        </small>
        <small class="error" ng-show="signup_form.email.$error.email">
          This is not a valid email
        </small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type='submit' class="button radius">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Typing email...:

[image: Invalid email]

still typing - making it valid...:

[image: Valid email]

Label has disagreed it is showing back when I click anywhere on the page.

Angular.js : `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js`

I don't use any custom css.

Chrome Inspect for invalid:

[image: Valid inspect]

Chrome inspect for valid:

[image]

Comment: seems like label is effecting when error div is hiding try to add `<br />` after the label and it will work.

Comment: adding <br /> makes it work. Can you elaborate on the reasons for it  in the answer?

Comment: yeah that's strange :( lol